# Why this next.js and typescript page says "Property 'data' does not exist on type"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am starting to use typescript with next.js

```
const Index: NextPage = (props) => {

  return (<p>{prop.data.name}</p>);

}
export default Index;

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
        `${server}/api`
    ).then((response) => response.json());
    return {
        props: {data}
    };
};
```

my editor highlight the word data in {props.data.name} with this message

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

how can I define a type from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a type and pass it to the generic param of `NextPage` like below

```
type PictureType = {
   category: string,
   createdAt: string,
   favourites: number,
   isHidden: boolean,
   title: string,
   updatedAt: string,
   url: string,
   user: string,
}
type ResponseDataType = {
   lastPictures: PictureType[],
   picturesByCat: PictureType[]
}
type PageProps = {
   data: ResponseDataType, 
}
const Index: NextPage<PageProps> = (props) => {

  return (<p>{prop.data.name}</p>);

}
export default Index;

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
        `${server}/api`
    ).then((response) => response.json());
    return {
        props: {data}
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure what should I use in place of any.  Can I use something like JSON or just []?

Comment: You can define that type based on your data structure from `data`. If you can share that data response's structure, I can help you to check that part too @user3174311

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1K2kWL1k0TbG0Nlyh1ePzoP04R7uRHXey?usp=sharing

Comment: I added other types to fit your response data, but I think it's not perfect for your case due to a lack of other info. But hopefully, from this, you can briefly have ideas of how to set types from responses @user3174311